How do I combine an existing Android application with an Android application based on the LibGDX framework?
I have a basic android application created in Android Studio. And there is an android application created through the LibGDX framework to work with 3D models. How do I combine them into a single application where I can use classes from both the regular android and the LibGDX framework, as well as use Intent.
There is no way to combine them. I ask you very much to help, to explain clearly and intelligibly for the kettle.

It's possible I'm missing something because I've never used libGDX, but...what is stopping you? Can't you just use the classes? https://libgdx.com/wiki/start/a-simple-game uses android.os.Bundle, for example.
